# Replication invariance of weighted sums

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, economics

Consider the following function:

- $\phi(\langle x_1,x_2,...,x_n \rangle) = \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2
     + ... + \alpha_n x_n$,

where $x_1, x_2, ...$ are all real numbers such that $x_1≤x_2≤...$ and we also have $\alpha_1 ≥ \alpha_2 ≥ ... > 0$.

Now consider the following property:

- $\phi(\langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle) = \phi(\langle y_1,...,y_n
     \rangle)$

  if and only if, for all $m≥1$,

  $\phi(\langle \underbrace{x_1,\ldots,x_1}_{m\text{
     times}},...,\underbrace{x_n,\ldots,x_n}_{m\text{
     times}}\rangle)=\phi(\langle \underbrace{y_1,\ldots,y_1}_{m\text{
     times}},...,\underbrace{y_n,\ldots,y_n}_{m\text{ times}}\rangle)$.

My question is: Is it true that if this property holds, then $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 =\dots$?

Or, to put it differently, if a weighted sum with positive coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots$ is invariant to replication, as it were, does it follow that the coefficients are in fact equal?

I am inclined to think Yes. This *seems* to be a corollary of Proposition 7 in [Ebert (1988)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00735758), but I am sure a proof simpler than his is possible. Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Could you please clarify notation a bit? It looks like you have defined $\phi$ on both $\mathbb{R}^n$ and also on $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. Are we to assume that there are countably many $(\alpha_k)$ ?

Comment: Yes. I meant for $\phi$ to apply to a vector of real numbers of any length and to each time draw weights from some single (countably infinite) sequence of weights. But I want to avoid comparing the values of $\phi$ for vectors of different sizes. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: This problem seems like an excellent candidate for MO problems.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is affirmative. We do induction on $N$ to prove $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \dots = \alpha_N$ as follows.

First of all, the base case $N = 2$ is proved in the bottom(the proof of this case actually automatically implies the case for arbitrary $N$). We next finish the process by showing that case $N = k$ implies case $N = k+1$(for $k \geq 2$):

When $k$ is odd, substitute $n = 2$ and $m = \frac{k+1}{2}$ in the property yields $$ \frac{k+1}{2} \alpha_1 = \frac{k-1}{2} \alpha_1 + \alpha_{k+1} .$$
Hence $\alpha_{1} = \alpha_{k+1}$.

When k is even,  substitute $n = 2$ and $m = \frac{k}{2} + 1$ in the property yields $$ ( \frac{k}{2} + 1 ) \alpha_1 = ( \frac{k}{2} - 1 )\alpha_1 + \alpha_{k+1} + \alpha_{k+2}.$$
Hence $2 \alpha_1 = \alpha_{k+1} + \alpha_{k+2}$. Note that $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \geq ... > 0$. We have $ \alpha_1 = \alpha_{k+1} = \alpha_{k+2}$.

The process of induction is therefore now finished. In conclusion, we have $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 =\dots.$

---

Proof of the case $N = 2$:

Let $p = \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}{\alpha_1}$ and $q = \frac{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3}{\alpha_1}$. We prove $p = 2$ and $q = 3$ at one strike. By repeatedly applying the property, it's easy to show the following equalities:$$\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{2^{n_1}} = p^{n_1} \alpha_1,$$and $$\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{3^{n_2}} = q^{n_2}\alpha_1$$for arbitrary positive integers $n_1$ and $n_2$. Taking the quotient of these equalities yields$$ \frac{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{3^{n_2}}}{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{2^{n_1}}} = \frac{q^{n_2}}{p^{n_1}}.$$
Now taking sufficiently large $n_1$ and $n_2$ that satisfy $2^{n_1} < 3^{n_2} < 2^{n_1+1}$ yields $p = 2$ and $q = 3$ since we have estimation(recall $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \geq ... > 0$)$$1 < \frac{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{3^{n_2}}}{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{2^{n_1}}} < 2$$for arbitrary $n_1$ and $n_2$ that satisfy $2^{n_1} < 3^{n_2} < 2^{n_1+1}$. We're through.

(Note that this actually implies $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 =\dots $ directly, since if $ \frac{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{3^{n_2}}}{\alpha_1 + \dots + \alpha_{2^{n_1}}} = \frac{3^{n_2}}{2^{n_1}}$, then $ \alpha_1 = \dots = \alpha_{3^{n_2}}. $)

Comment: Of course we could substitute other $m$ in the property to get (much more) stronger result for a fixed $k$, the present choice of $m$ is only for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I don't see why the case $ N = 2 $ is easy to prove. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Also, when you set $ n = 2 $ in the induction step, what do you take $ x _ 1 $, $ x _ 2 $, $ y _ 1 $ and $ y _ 2 $ to be?

Comment: I got to admit that I underestimated the difficulty to prove the case =2
, as you can see above, my proof of the case =2
 automatically proves the result for arbitrary . So in some sense, all the essentially difficulty lies in the case =2. By the way, We don’t need to take any specific value of x and y in the original 'proof', essentially we’ve obtained an equality of single-variable-linear-functions which can take infinitely many values, therefore the desired equality of coefficients for a fixed  then follows.